# How do you know a particular view is a personal view or a public view?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list-view

Is there a way you can distinguish a view whether it's a public view or a personal view ?

Answer (score 4):

When you click the view in the list or library look at the URL. With a personal view you will find the URL looks something like:

Site/Lists/ListName/PersonalViews.aspx?

Comment: This might not apply to modern SharePoint Online sites. This probably applies to on prem SharePoint 2013 installations but nothing cloud based.

Answer (score 3):

The previous answer is right, you can do it also by powershell, with the property **PersonalView**.

```
$site = Get-SPSite http://yourSite
$web = $site.OpenWeb()
$list=$web.Lists["your List name"]
#get the index of your view
$list.Views[0].PersonalView #true or false
```

[SPView properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Microsoft.SharePoint.SPView_properties.aspx)

If you want a more user friendly way, you can add this code into a script editor in the view page:

```
<div id="viewType"></div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        if(window.location.href.indexOf("PersonalViews")>-1){
            $("#viewType").html("Personal View");
        }else{
            $("#viewType").html("Public View");
        }
    });
<script>
```

Comment: Yes, I believe you can use those methods as well, But is there's another way ? A more user friendly method?

Comment: I updated my anwser with a javascript solution